# Errno::EACCES error when testing code in development on localhost

Tags: ruby, file-access, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Get this error when running this code:

```
<% content_for :game do %>
<% gamefolder = Dir.open(`#{Rails.root}/public/browserGames/#{@browserGame.slug}`) %>
<% gameFolder.each do |file| %>
  <% if file.match?(/.js/) %>
    <script src=<%= `#{Rails.root}/public/browserGames/#{@browserGame.slug}` + file %>></script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It stops me on line 2 and gives the Errno::EACCES error.  I am simply running this on localhost in development mode.  Wanting to make sure everything works before I try to deploy and find similar issues.

What I am trying to accomplish with this code is to load the js files for the specific game trying to be played in the window.

I am also open to trying other ways of achieving the goal, but I have different games on here and want to make sure I am only loading the specific files for the selected game.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/browserGames/test/*.js"]
```

instead of opening open for dir.
and use `<script src="<%= file %>"></script>`

Comment: Your answer worked great for accessing the files I needed.  I had to modify the script tag a little to get it to work exactly right, but all is well now.  Thank you for the help.